# Cannot call CakePHP setFlash function

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

My client inherited an incomplete CMS and I am trying to help them fix it. Keep in mind that I come from front end development, some logic that may appear obvious to some of you totally elude me.

So I managed to almost complete and better the CMS, however there is the issue of logging in. If a user enters the right username and password, all works properly.

However, it would be simple courtesy to indicate to the user when something wrong was done, like "retry to enter your password" or some better phrased message. But nothing happens now.

So I looked into the code, ended up comparing these two files:

login.ctp (the view, as I understand it)

```
<?php
    echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
?>

<div id="loginColumns">

    <!-- input fields -->
    <div id="loginLeftColumn">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>'login'));
            echo $this->Form->input('username');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
        ?>
    </div>

    <!-- login button -->
    <div id="loginRightColumn">
        <?php echo $this->Form->end('Continue'); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

UsersController.php (the controller, as the name implies)

```
<?php
    class UsersController extends AppController
    {
        var $name = 'Users';
        public $scaffold;


        public function beforeFilter()
        {
            $this -> Auth -> allow(array('login', 'logout'));
        }


        public function login()
        {
            if($this -> request -> is('post'))
            {
                if($this -> Auth -> login())
                {
                    $this -> redirect($this -> Auth -> redirect());
                }
                else
                {
                    // this does not work, maybe because there is no session yet
                    // when users have not logged in yet?
                    $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
                }
            }
        }


        function logout()
        {
            $this -> redirect($this -> Auth -> logout());
        }
    }
?>
```

As you can see, there seems to be something that handles erros when logging, but there is nothing showing. That setFlash function is used in a couple of places once the user is logged in, and it works like a charm.

Is there any way for me to use it before the user logs in, or do I have to recreate it from scratch? And if so, what could be some leads into doing it so it looks and feels similar?

Thanks!

Comment: only thing I can suggest is the cake manual suggests adding **both** these lines to your view/layout: `echo $this->Session->flash();
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');`, frankly I can't see why it should make a difference; but it's in the cookbook.

Comment: @Ross Hey you know what, it actually made the difference, it totally worked! I'd love to understand what this did, but that's great, thanks!

Comment: @Ross but it worked only once... it's not repeatable, it doesn't work anymore...

Comment: I assume you've logged out before trying again - you can still access the login page even if you're logged in; unless you specifically check `if($this->Auth->user()) { // redirect } // login.. `

Comment: I guess it must have been that, although for a while I simply could not log in even... So I stopped the server, restarted it, tried to log in, logged out, then tried with your code, it seems to work now. I'll try that exception in case the user is logged in already.

Comment: Functional again, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick with using this in your view:

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

This will display the Flash message you are setting in the controller.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't do anything. I tried What @Ross suggested earlier, it worked once, and then I could never repeat it. I tried your option too, to no avail...

Comment: As Ross mentions above, make sure you are logged out before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/View/Layouts/default.ctp` file add the line:

```
<?php  
   echo $this->Session->flash(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

check and add "session" component if it is not set by default in your AppController class, then add

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('your message'); ?>
```

to your view!